# How do i this query in Django views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

How can I get password of a user that his email is `user@email.com`, my Model is like below:

```
class user_registration_data(models.Model):
      name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
      Address=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
      Password=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
      Email=models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: `user_registration_data.objects.get(Email='user@email.com').Password`.

However, this is a strange thing to want to do, since Django handles user authentication out of the box - plus, you should never store passwords as plain text.

*Please* go through the official Django tutorial from start to finish. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

you can use Django ORM like below:
`user_registration_data.objects.filter(Email='user@email.com')`

and for you knowledge every class that implemented in django should be CamelCase. so your model should be like this :

```
class UserRegistrationData(models.Model):
      name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
      Address=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
      Password=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
      Email=models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank=False)
```

and see this article for your info:
https://realpython.com/python-pep8/

Answer (score 0):

In your views, you can get the password by:

```sql
user_registration_data.objects.values("Password").get(Email="user@email.com")
```

If you are creating Custom User Model, then it should inherit from AbstractBaseUser or you can extend the user model. Follow the documentation on [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).